# What is the formal proof that the reciprocal of a number approaches 0 as the number increases without bound?

Tags: calculus, limits

In Calculus textbooks it seems assumed that
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} = 0 ,$$
meaning that "the limit of the reciprocal of $n$ as $n$ increases without bound is zero".

This makes intuitive sense: if $a/b$ gives the (potentially fractional) number of times $b$ fits into $a$, then as $b$ increases without bound, $a/b$ should get increasingly small.

What would be the formal proof that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} = 0?$$

---

More generally, this is usually expressed as
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a}{n} = 0 ,$$
though if $a$ does not contain $n$ it gives the same result,
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a}{n} = a \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} = a(0) = 0 .$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the set $A = \{1/n\mid n\in\mathbb{N}_{>0}\}$.

Clearly, it is bounded below by $0$ and it is not empty. Consequently, it admits an infimum $L\geq 0$.

Suppose that $L > 0$. Hence $2L > L$, which means there exists an $n_{0}$ such that $2L > 1/n_{0}$.

In other words, we have just proven that $L > 1/2n_{0}$, which contradicts our assumption.

Thus we can conclude that $\inf(A) = 0$.

Now we are ready to prove the proposed claim. More precisely, we want to prove the following proposition:
\begin{align*}
(\forall\varepsilon > 0)(\exists n_{0}\in\mathbb{N}_{>0})\:\text{s.t.}\left(n\geq n_{0}\Rightarrow \frac{1}{n} < \varepsilon\right)
\end{align*}

Indeed, this is the case.

Let us consider an arbitrary positive real number $\varepsilon > 0$.

Given that $\varepsilon > \inf(A)$, there exists an $n_{0}$ such that $\varepsilon > 1/n_{0}$.

Consequently, for every $\varepsilon  > 0$, there corresponds an $n_{0}\in\mathbb{N}_{>0}$ such that
\begin{align*}
n\geq n_{0} \Rightarrow \frac{1}{n} \leq \frac{1}{n_{0}} < \varepsilon
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answer!  A couple questions:
Why are $n$ and $n_0$ positive natural numbers ($\mathbb{N}_{>0}$) rather than positive real numbers ($\mathbb{R}_{>0}$)?
Second, could you clairify what is the assumption that $L > 1/{2 n_0}$ contradicts?  I assume it's a contradiction because $1/{2 n_0} \in A$, and the infimum $L$ of set $A$ must be less than or equal to every element of $A$; however I would appreciate clarification on this point.

Comment: @zandroidius the answer to the first question is: because the sequences' domain is the set of natural numbers instead of the real numbers. The answer to the second question is exactly what you said: if $L > 0$ were a lower bound, it should be less than or equal to every element of $A$, which is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

To show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac 1n=0$, we need to show that, for every $\epsilon$, there exists a threshold $n_0$ for which, if $n>n_0$, then $\left|\frac 1n\right|\leq \epsilon.$

Take any $n_0$ greater than $1/\epsilon$. Then, for any $n>n_0$,
$$0\leq \frac 1n<\frac{1}{n_0}<\epsilon,$$
and we are done.

(This last chain of inequalities corresponds to $1/\epsilon<n_0<n$.)

Answer (score 1):

We make the concept of "approach" in limits rigorous through epsilon-delta proofs, which you can look up.

Here is the proof for your limit: [limit as $x$ approaches infinity of $\frac{1}{x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1276646/limit-as-x-approaches-infinity-of-frac1x)

Answer (score 0):

Hint

You are actually referring to the limit of a sequence

$$1, (1/2), (1/3), \cdots $$

rather than the limit of a function.

Given $\epsilon > 0,~$ take $M \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ such that $$\frac{1}{\epsilon} < M.$$