# Prove the existence of $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $0<1/n<\epsilon$

Tags: inequality, upper-lower-bounds, natural-numbers

I'm seeking to prove that for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists an $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
$$
  0<\frac{1}{n}<\epsilon.
$$

I think that—in some form—I'm going to need to use the fact that for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$, we can find $a\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $a\geq x$ (i.e. the Archimedean property).

Or perhaps I could construct a set with an infimum of zero and somehow use that to generate an element between zero and $\epsilon$.

What's the most sensible approach here?

Comment: Don't you thing that if n is a natural number, then range of $\frac{1}{n}= (0,1]$ . And if that's the case, then there is always a natural number n for which $0<\frac{1}{n}<\epsilon$.

Comment: @NandeeshBhatrai What you've written claims there is a natural number $n$ such that $1/n = 1/\sqrt{2}$. I suspect you don't believe this.

Comment: Oh ya. Completely forgot those cases but atleast you agree that $\frac{1}{n}$ can be really close to $0$ if $\epsilon$ is very small and if it is greater than $1$ then $n$ can be any natural number.@preferred_anon

Comment: "I'm going to need to use the fact that for any x∈R, we can find a∈N such that a≥x (i.e. the Archimedean property)."  Exactly.  Let $x = \frac 1\epsilon$.  So $n > \frac 1\epsilon$ means $\frac 1n$ is .....?

Comment: "Don't you thing that if n is a natural number, then range of 1n=(0,1] ."  I most certainly do not.  I believe the range is a *subset* of $(0,1]$ but not equal to $(0,1]$.  If then $\inf(Range\ of\ \frac 1n) = 0$ I'm good and we can intuitively think that is obvious but.... we do have to prove that.  "you agree that 1n can be really close to 0 if ϵ is very small and if it is greater than 1 then n can be any natural number" Yes, that that's just restating what you have to prove and claiming "It's obvious".  It's not obvious and we do have to prove it.

Comment: "Or perhaps I could construct a set with an infimum of zero".  The perfect set for that would be $A = \{\frac 1n| n\in \mathbb N\}$.  Can you prove $\inf A = 0$.  It's clear that $\frac 1n > 0$ for all $n$ so $\inf A \ge 0$.  Can you prove $\inf A > 0$ is impossible?  Note $\inf A \le .....< \frac 1{n+2} < \frac 1{n+1} < \frac 1{n} < \frac 1{n-1}<...$..... Can you use this to prove $0 < \inf A \le ..... < \frac 1{n+2} < \frac 1{n+1} < \frac 1n <\frac 1{n-1}<....$?

Comment: So the question is *how* to get insight.  I guess if worse comes to worst you can always attempt to *solve*  $0<\frac 1n < \epsilon$.  So $0< 1 < n\epsilon$ and $0 < \frac 1{\epsilon} < n$.  SO $n > \frac 1\epsilon$ is required.  ..."I'm going to need to use the fact that for any x∈R, we can find a∈N such that a≥x (i.e. the Archimedean property)."  YEP.  so $x =\frac 1\epsilon$.....

Comment: This may help you https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3953398/what-is-the-formal-proof-that-the-reciprocal-of-a-number-approaches-0-as-the-num/3953409#3953409

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: that $0 < \frac 1n < \epsilon \iff n > \frac 1\epsilon > 0$

So you have to show:

1. If $\epsilon > 0$ then $\frac 1{\epsilon}$ exists (that's easy; $\mathbb R$ is a field so multiplicative inverses exist).
2. If $\epsilon > 0$ then $\frac 1{\epsilon} > 0$.  (You should have proven that already and can take that as a given without even acknowledging it is in question.)[The proof is If $\frac 1\epsilon \le 0$ and $\epsilon > 0$ we would have $1 =\frac 1\epsilon \cdot \epsilon \le 0\cdot \epsilon = 0$; a contradiction].
3. For any $M = \frac 1{\epsilon}\in \mathbb R$, there exists a natural number $n: n> M$.

And 3: (which says nothing more or less than "The Natural numbers are not bounded above") is the real heart of the issue.

Depending on the level of the book you may or may not be able to take that for granted.

But it *is* equivalent to the Archimedian principal.  $1 > 0$ so for any $M =\frac 1{\epsilon} \in \mathbb R$ there is an $n\in \mathbb N$ so that $n*1 > M$.

.....

To sum up:

$\epsilon > 0$.

So $\frac 1{\epsilon} > 0$.

So there exists an $n\in \mathbb N$ so that $n > \frac 1\epsilon$.

So $0 < \frac 1n < \epsilon$.

That's all you have to do.

Answer (score 3):

You have almost said it yourself if you accept the Archimedian property: Let $\epsilon > 0$. Then there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that

$$n > \frac{1}{\epsilon} \implies \epsilon > \frac{1}{n}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider $n$ equal to $\lceil\frac{1}{\epsilon} \rceil$ (that means the smallest natural number that is greater or equal to $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$). Then you can easily see that
$$0<\frac{1}{n} = \frac{1}{\lceil\frac{1}{\epsilon}\rceil} <\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\epsilon}}=\epsilon,$$
so for any $\epsilon\in\mathbb{R}$, you can just pick $n\in\mathbb{N}$ that way and the condition is verified (for that $n$ and for any other natural number grater that $n$).